# Geometric Brownian motion with volatility as function of time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

With the following process:
$$dS_t = r S_t dt + σ(t) St dW_t \tag1$$

and

$$ \sigma (t) = 0.1 \ \ \ if \ \  t < 0.5  \\ \sigma (t) = 0.21 \ \ \  otherwise$$

I know the general solution should be :
$$S_t = S_0 e^{rt − \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sigma (s)^2 ds +\int_0^t \sigma (s) dW_s} \tag2 $$

and if $log(S_t) = Z_t$

$$Z_t = Z_0 + rt − \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sigma (s)^2 ds +\int_0^t \sigma (s) dW_s \tag3 $$

My question is how to treat the integration if $t \geq 0.5$? I think I need to split the integration but I am not sure how to compute the integration in the half open interval $t \in [0, 0.5)$. Should the upper bond of the integral for $t \in [0, 0.5)$ be treated as a number with a limit approaching 5?

For computational simulation on discrete time, I know if the volatility is a constant, I can use (4) below for simulation in discrete time. ($\delta W_s$ is just normal distribution of variance $\delta t$)
$$Z_{t+\delta t} = Z_t + (rt − \frac{1}{2} \sigma )\delta t  +\sigma \delta W_s \tag4 $$
However, I am not sure how to simulate especially when the time progresses from $t < 0.5$ to $t >  0.5$

Comment: you could try approximate this volatility by a continuous piecewise approximation i.e. for $t\in (0.5-\epsilon,0.5)$ drawing a line connecting $0.1$ to $0.21$. Then you can try to investigate what happens to the general solution as $\epsilon\to 0$.